# In Russia, are the anniversaries of the various events that occurred in 1917 and '18 observed according to the Old Style or the New Style calendar?

Tags: soviet-union, russia, world-war-one, calendar

In Russia in 1917 and 1918, a number of important events, including the abdication and assassination of Czar Nicholas, and the Menshevik and Bolshevik revolutions occurred while the Old Style (Julian) calendar was in use. But within a few months of these events, the New Style (Gregorian) calendar was adopted in Soviet Russia.

Do the Russians mark the anniversaries of these events by the Julian Calendar, in which they occurred, or in the Gregorian Calendar?

For instance, is the abdication of the Tsar considered to have occurred on March 2 or March 15?

Comment: There was no such thing as "the Menshevik revolution".

Answer (score 8):

None of the events are celebrated in Russia nowadays. In Soviet times, only the day of the [October Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October_Revolution) was celebrated, on the [7th November](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_the_Soviet_Union), which is according to the New-Style calendar. In history textbooks, both dates for a particular event (e.g., abdication of the czar) are usually given.

Answer (score 7):

According to the new style. Even though the Revolution is called "October Revolution", it is celebrated in November, which may be confusing to some.

The date of the Tsar's abdication is not celebrated and totally unknown to the masses.